# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '7775-683756' for key 'camera_from_to_unique'

Tags: mysql

This is the table layout:

```
CREATE TABLE camera
(
    entity_id VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    area_type INT(11) NOT NULL,
    type INT(11),
    `from` INT(11),
    `to` INT(11),
    severity INT(11) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(255),
    additional_information VARCHAR(255),
    location POINT NOT NULL,
    reported_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
    road_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    ugc TINYINT(1) COMMENT 'user generated content',
    event INT(11),
    advice VARCHAR(255),
    updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX camera_from_to_unique ON camera (`from`, `to`);
```

And this is the query:

```
INSERT INTO `camera`
             (
              `entity_id`,
              `area_type`,
              `type`,
              `from`,
              `to`,
              `severity`,
              `description`,
              `additional_information`,
              `location`,
              `reported_at`,
              `road_id`,
              `ugc`,
              `event`,
              `advice`
             ) VALUES (
              :id_28,
              :area_type_28,
              :type_28,
              :from_28,
              :to_28,
              :severity_28,
              :description_28,
              :additional_information_28,
              POINT(:position_x_28, :position_y_28),
              :reported_at_28,
              :road_id_28,
              :ugc_28,
              :event_28,
              :advice_28
             ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
              `entity_id` = :id_28,
              `area_type` = :area_type_28,
              `type` = :type_28,
              `from` = :from_28,
              `to` = :to_28,
              `severity` = :severity_28,
              `description` = :advice_28,
              `additional_information` = :description_28,
              `location` = POINT(:position_x_28, :position_y_28),
              `reported_at` = :reported_at_28,
              `road_id` = :road_id_28,
              `ugc` = :ugc_28,
              `event` = :event_28,
              `advice` = :advice_28
```

And these are the binded parameters:

```
array (
  'id_28' => 'NLSIT0020843410',
  'area_type_28' => 1,
  'type_28' => 46,
  'from_28' => 7775,
  'to_28' => 683756,
  'severity_28' => 80,
  'description_28' => '',
  'additional_information_28' => 'Tussen knp. Hattemerbroek en Zwolle-Noord',
  'position_x_28' => 6.032483,
  'position_y_28' => 52.490729000000002,
  'reported_at_28' => '2017-01-06 16:43:00',
  'road_id_28' => 621453,
  'ugc_28' => 0,
  'event_28' => 1072,
  'advice_28' => '',
)
```

I thought that because my `from` and `to` field are both in the same unique index in my table, the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` would be triggered, but apparently that is not the case.

Could someone please explain why my `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is not triggered so the data gets updated instead of this mysql error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplicate key update part of the insert is being activated. However the attempt to update the row instead of inserting is failing. Because of this.

```
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
          `entity_id` = :id_28,
          `area_type` = :area_type_28,
          `type` = :type_28,
          `from` = :from_28,   /* this one */
          `to` = :to_28,       /* and this one */
```

YOu are trying to force mysql to have the same values for the from and to columns that triggered the duplicate. You need to remove those two columns from the ON DUPLICATE KEY clause. So we have

```
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
          `entity_id` = :id_28,
          `area_type` = :area_type_28,
          `type` = :type_28,
          `severity` = :severity_28,
          `description` = :advice_28,
          `additional_information` = :description_28,
          `location` = POINT(:position_x_28, :position_y_28),
          `reported_at` = :reported_at_28,
          `road_id` = :road_id_28,
          `ugc` = :ugc_28,
          `event` = :event_28,
          `advice` = :advice_28
```

Comment: Glad to have helped